# how to pass the url like this to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Q: how to pass the url like this to facebook.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=XBOX&u=http://aaa.com/#/project/xbox-branding

when I passed this url to facebook, facebook modify the url to

http://aaa.com/project/xbox-branding

in the facebook's post my shared url can't link to correct url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encode `#` to `%23`, you can do this with [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=XBOX&u=http://aaa.com/%23/project/xbox-branding
```

but you should encode the full redirect URL like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=XBOX&u=http%3A%2F%2Faaa.com%2F%23%2Fproject%2Fxbox-branding
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=XBOX&u=http://aaa.com/%23/project/xbox-branding/" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">CLICK ME</a>


<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always encode the url to escape special characters.

In js,

```
'https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=XBOX&u=' + encodeURIComponent('http://aaa.com/#/project/xbox-branding');
```

In php,

```
'https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=XBOX&u='.urlencode('http://aaa.com/#/project/xbox-branding');
```

Comment: I already tried with urlencode. it is return http%3A%2F%2Fsurfaceunderfire.com%2F%23%2Fproject%2Fxbox-branding. this is not working.

Comment: Its working for me. Share it on facebook and click from facebook and check it returns to correct url.

Comment: there is a typo for the js part, it is encodeURIComponent and not encodeUriComponent

Answer (score -1):

ans : change # to %23 in the url. e.g http://aaa.com/%23/project/......

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer. Your answer does not suggest a solution, it only points out the problem.